# Moving Average block returns wrong values for column vector input

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink, moving-average

I am using Simulink for real-time classification using a trained Fine-KNN model. The input data for the model is a 50-point moving average vector [6x1]. I am using the DSP moving average block for this purpose with sliding window technique (window size = 50 and simulating using code generator). When I compare the input and the output of this block for real-time values, I get the following plot:

[image: Plot]

It is clear from the plot that there is something wrong with the output as there is quite a discrepancy between the input and the output. What could possibly be the problem or am I doing something wrong?

Edit (after Cris's comment):

Here are some screenshots to showcase some modeling parameters within Simulink:

1. Screenshot showing probes for measuring actual input and moving average output along with the Moving Average block parameters
   [Probes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjM59.jpg)
2. Other block parameters that might be affecting the performance of the model:
   a. [OPC Config real-time block parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01FC2.jpg)
   b. [OPC Read block parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRih9.jpg)

PS: One issue that I can think of is that the actual input is fed to the Moving Average in real-time at 10ms time-step and I am not sure if the moving average block has a buffer to store up to the "Window Length" data as it keeps coming in. What I mean by this is, the moving average block might not have access to 50 values of the input signals for quite some time and I am not sure how it deals with that kind of a situation.

Comment: It is hard to know what is wrong without seeing any code.

Comment: The "ramp" at the start is due to your PS, i.e. it's using 0 in the buffer when there aren't enough samples, causing the average to ramp in. However, your actual issue is caused by the issue demonstrated in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this with the following minimal example:

[image: blocks]

So a constant input of `[1; 2; 3]` gives a moving average of roughly `2` (the average of the input elements) in all elements, when you would expect an output of `[1; 2; 3]` since each element is constant.

In your example, the inputs average approximately `0.62`, which you are seeing in the output from the moving average.

Using a `demux` to split your vector up gives the desired output

[image: demux example]

The docs say that the moving average block should be able to handle this though

> The Moving Average block computes the moving average of the input signal along each channel independently over time.

It turns out that a `channel` in this case is a *column* of your vector. Since you have a column vector, the columns in each iteration are getting stacked and averaged. Unfortunately the underlying code is sealed so we can't check this theory other than by trying it out.

**Reshape your input to be a row array using the `reshape` block.**
Then you get the expected output

[image]

Comment: Reshaping the input to row vector solved the issue with inaccurate outputs. Thanks.